# Why don't absolute paths work when importing typescript files into other typescript files but are otherwise ok, in a React Native Project?

Tags: typescript, react-native, absolute-path

**Backstory:**

I am gradually converting an existing React Native project to TypeScript. Absolute paths have been working for years based on my `babelrc` configuration.

**Problem:**

Since adding TypeScript, absolute paths work only in the following scenarios:

- importing `js` files into other `js` files
- importing `ts` files into `js` files
- importing `js` files into `ts` files

The thing that does not work is:

- importing `ts` files into other `ts` files

It appears to work in VSCode but when I try to build my app, I get the infamous:

> {insert file here} could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules, etc.

I have spent weeks trying to figure this out. Absolute paths with TypeScript seems to be a challenge a lot of people run into. I've tinkered with my `babelrc`, `tsconfig`, `eslintrc`, and `metro.config.js` with a myriad of combinations and additions/subtractions. I've installed dependencies, I've tried everything the error suggests(deleting caches, restarting, etc.). I've played with the import statements and scoured the docs until I was black and blue, reinstalled `node_modules` and `pods`.

The ONLY thing that has worked(besides relative imports, but ew) is adding a `package.json` to the folder I am trying to import from like so:

```
{
  "name": "app"
}
```

This seems simple enough but I can't accept that this is the only way. And as I convert more and more files, I don't really want to have to keep sprinkling `package.json`s everywhere like some overworked typescript fairy :)

I don't want to make this too long so if anyone thinks it would be beneficial to see my config files, I can for sure add them. Especially hoping for an answer referenced by official sources. Super appreciate anyone's help!